# How can I do computation on disk in Spark instead of RAM?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am newbie to spark and want to run Spark Program on disk.I want to load RDD on disk instead of RAM how can i do that ?

Comment: Are you talking about RDD caching? If you don't explicitly tell Spark to cache an RDD, it won't. It'll just process it from disk. But Spark will use some memory to do its work, just like Hadoop or any other tool will use memory. That's unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

use RDD.cache(DISK_ONLY)

It stores the RDD partitions only on disk.